# Selecting next div jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to select the `.next()` div to work within a carousel.

However, it seems to be returning all `.children()` rather than the `.next()`

**HTML**

```
<nav class="slider-navigation">
  <div class="left-arrow"></div>
  <div class="right-arrow"></div>
</nav>

<div class="slides">
  <div class="slide" id="slide1"></div>
  <div class="slide" id="slide2"></div>
  <div class="slide" id="slide3"></div>
  <div class="slide" id="slide4"></div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(".left-arrow").click(function () {

  var currentSlide = $(this).parent().siblings(".slides").children().next();

  // Do something with currentSlide.

});
```

When I `console.log(currentSlide)` in the browser it returns all 4 children of `.slides`.

*The same happens for* `$(".right-arrow").click()` *I just did not want to add duplicate code*

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: we will need to see some more code, perhaps even a fiddle, cause it is not clear what you are trying to achieve. How do you determine what slide is next? Perhaps something like `$('.slide:visible').next()`may work, all though I would probably store some sort of pointer to determine what slide is active.

Comment: [$.fn.next](http://api.jquery.com/next/) finds the next element for each element in the collection you call it on.  You're getting all the children of a div, and then calling `.next()` on it.  This will return all the items found by `.children()`, excluding the first.  You need to call `.next()` on the current item, not on the whole collection.  Without identifying the "current" item, the is no way to determine the "next".

Comment: @PeterVR I am trying to get a carousel slider working. I am currently doing it by pulling the whole slider left or right according to the arrow the has been clicked. I don't want to do it this way so I am trying to find a solution to get it working by adding a higher z-index to the next .slide than the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another option is to set the first element to the "current" class and use it to start the navigation between the slides.

*on prev control click, if there is no element before this one so nothing will happen and vice versa, so that's ok but if you want it to change direction after the last/first element got the "current" class so tell me and i will update the code...

Here it is:

HTML:

```
<nav class="slider-navigation">
  <div class="left-arrow">left</div>
  <div class="right-arrow">right</div>
</nav>

<div class="slides">
  <div class="slide current" id="slide1"></div>
  <div class="slide" id="slide2"></div>
  <div class="slide" id="slide3"></div>
  <div class="slide" id="slide4"></div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".left-arrow").click(function(){
        $('.current').prev().addClass('current');
        $('.current:first').next().removeClass('current');
    });
    $(".right-arrow").click(function(){
        $('.current').next().addClass('current');
        $('.current:last').prev().removeClass('current');
    });
});
```

live example: http://jsfiddle.net/spvLpjct (i've put some CSS to help you understand it).

Comment: This looks similar to the type of thing i am trying to do, however I want the none .current div be behind the .current one and fade in using after adding a higher z-index than the one on .current. Does that make sense?

Comment: sound like something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/spvLpjct/1/, i've used opacity instead of z-index but you can change it if you want to.

Comment: Sort of, yes. But how would you handle a case when the last slide is visible and a .right-arrow is clicked?

Comment: it depends on what your trying to do...there are sliders that works like this (or an slider option), if current slide is the last you can only click prev and vice versa, but there are another option of getting back to the first slide.

Comment: Thanks, Eran. Do you have any links to example of this getting back to first slide. I think the example you showed me first time may be what I am after. If it is I will up-vote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the current slide is visible and the rest are hidden you could use:

```
$(".left-arrow").click(function () {

  var currentSlide = $(".slides > .slide:visible").next();

  // Do something with currentSlide.

});
```

Comment: I will see if this helps and get back to you soon.